# imacro increase attr=id by one digit after every loop

Tags: loops, increment, imacros

imacro - I need to increase `ATTR=ID:` by one after each loop

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:ygtvlabelel92
```

The ID: `ygtvlabelel92` must be `ygtvlabelel93` after loop and `ygtvlabelel94` ....etc

Answer (score 1):

```
set !var1 1
add !var1 {{!loop}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:ygtvlabelel9{{!var1}}
```

Comment: Thanxs, I knew I had to put a variable in place

Comment: Thanxs, I knew I had to put a variable in place, just did not know how to code. One more problem the code loops well until ATTR=ID:ygtvlabelel9 gets to ATTR=ID:ygtvlabele200 then I receive RuntimeError element Span specified by ID:ygtvlabelel9{{!VAR1}} was not found line 17 (Error code: - 921)

Comment: Just went through the ATTR=ID: code and saw that they not actually increment by 1 Is it possible to call TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:john , AG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:mike , AG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:albert ...etc I do have all the names in csv

Answer (score 0):

```
//this is the JavaScript code. You have to place this code inside .js file or it will not work
var macro;

macro ="CODE:";
macro +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=ID:ygtvlabelel{{counter}}"+"\n";

//set the counter
var counter=92;

for(var i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
iimSet("counter",counter)
iimPlay(macro)


//increase counter
counter++;
}//end of i loop
```

Comment: Thanxs for helping me just not sure how to call this .js within imacro

Comment: It's simple. Just paste this in .js file and run it. NOT .iim file! The code is ready you just have to manipulate the macro +="  "+"\n"; part. Think of it as JS cover for iMacros code .