# Click on Successive Links Using IMacro

Tags: loops, variables, firefox, position, imacros

I am trying to write a macro to add a digit to POS= after each loop, so that it clicks on successive links in my search results in http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php (type in any keyword under "Search the Entire Document Archive). I did something very similar to the user from [imacro increase attr=id by one digit after every loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894967/imacro-increase-attr-id-by-one-digit-after-every-loop)

My code works, but the macro starts clicking from the third search result onward. I have changed POS= 1,2,3 but anything less than POS=4 ends up clicking on sidebars, not the search results. What should I change to get the macro to start clicking from the first search result? Thanks for any insight!

```
set !var1 1
add !var1 {{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=4{{!var1}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*
BACK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links you are trying to click on all have a class with value "listLink" so if you include that in the tag logic you should be able to bypass the sidebar links.

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=CLASS:listLink
BACK
```